# Cors problem with SpringBoot and Vue.js using AzureAD

Tags: spring-boot, azure, vue.js, authentication, cors

I create application which consist of SpringBoot as backend and frontend Vue.js. The first required is authentication by Microsoft account. I mean , I have to check if user have existing account if yes hten he has access. I implemented connect with Azure AD during login process, when backend gets token from AzureAd with simple ifnormation about user then generates own token and later communication between front and backend uses this custom token without Azure AD.
I implemented it in SpringBoot with security it works correct, I mean I open browser, put endpoint adres and I get redirect to Sign In to Microsoft. After that backend get token with simple infomration about user
but the problem was occured when I implemented Login process by Vue.js. In short, user opens brower with login page, clicks login and it should redirect him to Sign In to Microsoft as I described previous
but it doesn't work. I put diagram, how I implemented it

[login flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/filUt.png)

It doesn't work becasue I have error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/*numer*/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=*idKlient*&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Analytics.Read..... (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

It looks like that, browser blocks redirect to SignIn because , it thinks, that the source is localhost:3000(Vue.js). I don't understand it becasue user uses localhost:3000/login when open application but frontend send request to backend and backend invokes login page to Microsoft, I mean localhost:8080/api/auth/login.
I noticed, that when I opened localhost:8080/api/auth/login, i'm redirected to other url to login Microsoft account. When I was starting work on this I thought it will pop-up page or maybe different page in browser to login but not the same page.
Why new page with login can't appear? This login page is ran by backend, so I expected it will be work like that

I saw something like that in other web app in internet. When I clicked Login with Microsoft, then I got new small page to put my username and password, but it wasn't the same page.

I have configuration in backend with Cors.
I created simple test endpoint in backend. When I don't use this configuration I have error about Cors(similar to currently problem) when I use my Cors configuration then requests and response work normall between backend and front only when I use endpoint with Azure AD there is problem. So I'm sure the problem is only with redirect to Microsoft login

Generally, I don't have idea how to resolve it. Where I should configure it? It is to fix or I have to change my architecture ?
Maybe you have some idea or you know why it happens
I don't want to change the architecture but if necessary I will have to. Is there any way to configure it, probably in Azure AD because I don't know if it is possible to change it somewhere else

P.S
I found the same problem but with angular in  [How to call spring security azure AD localhost:8080 from angular localhost:4200. Error in azure call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500895/how-to-call-spring-security-azure-ad-localhost8080-from-angular-localhost4200)
but I can't see any correct answer

**Edit 1:**
This is my cors configuration, I mentioned

```
    @Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}


  private void sharedSecurityConfiguration(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors(c-> c.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
}
```

Edit 2:
My application.properties

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id=<tenant-id>
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=<client-id>
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-secret=<key-secret>
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.authorization-clients.graph.scopes=https://graph.microsoft.com/Analytics.Read, email, profile, openid
```

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648712/spring-boot-post-request-error-blocking-cors-policy/76651003#76651003)

Comment: Try adding `@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")` on the controller class level.

Comment: @Eric and Mohammad Nayem
I have edited my post and I added my cors configuration. I think my configuration has AllowedOrigin setting so defines origins.  It is similar sollution to CrossOrigin but globally setting. So CrossOrigin doesn't work , I checked anyway

Comment: I have problem only with endpoint which invokes auth by Azure AD As I mentioned , I tested other endpoint(normall) and the frontend connects normally  with backend